# Testing transactions that should fail with anchor

Tags: anchor, testing, transaction, failed

I am currently writing unit test for my Solana contract written using the Anchor framework. I have created unit tests for the positive flow of how things should work, and all the tests are passing, but I cannot find any documentation on how to ensure that a certain transaction *should* fail (i.e. due to improper inputs or signature errors)

Does anyone have any resources where I can learn more about this, or if this is even possible with the current Anchor framework?

Answer (score 2):

Suppose you have your rust code like this

```
pub fn call(ctx: Context<Call>) -> Result<()>
{
   return Err(CallError::ErrorExpected.into())
}

pub struct Call<'info>
{
  #[account(mut)]
  pub from: Signer<'info>,
  
  pub to: AccountInfo<'info>,
}

#[error_code]
pub enum CallError 
{
    #[msg("An Error Occured")]
    ErrorExpected,
}
```

You can test for errors on client side like this

```
try{
  await program.methods
     .call()
     .accounts({
       from: provider.publicKey,
       to: toAccount.publicKey
     })
     .signers([])
     .rpc()
}
catch (error) {
      const errMsg = "An Error Occured";
      assert.equal((error as AnchorError).error.errorMessage, errMsg)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can assert the error logs:

```
it("Does not allow creating a pixel out of bounds", async () => {
    const x = 0
    const y = 200
    const [pixelPublicKey] = web3.PublicKey.findProgramAddressSync(
      [Buffer.from("pixel"), Buffer.from([x, y])],
      program.programId,
    )

    await program.methods
      .createPixel(x, y, 0, 0, 255)
      .accounts({
        pixel: pixelPublicKey,
        user: anchorProvider.wallet.publicKey,
        systemProgram: web3.SystemProgram.programId,
      })
      .rpc()
      .then(
        () => Promise.reject(new Error('Expected to error!')),
        (e: AnchorError) => {
          assert.ok(e.errorLogs.some(log => log.includes('InvalidYCoordinate') && log.includes('The given Y co-ordinate is not between 0-99.')))
        }
      );
  })
```